# C++ multisets: removing the last element

Tags: c++, multiset

How to remove the last element from a multiset. I tried passing the reverse iterator to the erase function but that is not allowed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of [Multiset erase last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992658/multiset-erase-last-element)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiset erase last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992658/multiset-erase-last-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every `reverse_iterator` has a `base()` function, that returns "normalized" iterator. You could use it like this:

```
auto e = ms.rbegin();
ms.erase((++e).base());
```

We must increment `e` before getting underlying iterator, because the base iterator refers to the element that is **next** to the element the reverse_iterator is pointing to.

Another solution is using `std::prev` function:

```
ms.erase(std::prev(ms.end())); // since C++11
```

If C++11 is not an option for you, you could implement it yourself:

```
// copy-pasted from cppreference
template<class BidirIt>
BidirIt prev(BidirIt it, 
             typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, -n);
    return it;
}
```

It's more simpler, than first, but I leave two solution, because earlier I described first example incorrectly.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Alternatively, `std::prev(std::end(ms))`

Comment: @chris, Please, look at answer again. My first explanation was incorrect.

Comment: @soon i tried the second one.. it gives an error saying prev is not a member of std

Comment: Is there any benefit to `std::prev` over `operator--` here?

Comment: @24n8 yes - it can be integrated into a more complex expression without fear of mutation or side-effects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete only one element then you can write

```
if ( !ms.empty() ) ms.erase( std::prev( ms.end() ) );
```

If you want to delete all elements with the given key equal to the last key then you can write

```
if ( !ms.empty() )
{
    auto p = ms.equal_range( *std::prev( ms.end() ) );
    ms.erase( p.first, p.second );
}
```

And at last if you want to delete all duplicates except one then you can write

```
if ( !ms.empty() )
{
    auto p = ms.equal_range( *std::prev( ms.end() ) );
    ms.erase( std::next( p.first ), p.second );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because multiset erase function takes iterator which is regular. So if you want to erase last element you should do like that.

```
//in C++11
multiset.erase(std::prev(multiset.end()));
//in C++98 
multiset.erase(--multiset.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
multiset<int> mySet;
```

read in some integers.....

```
multiset<int>::reverse_iterator rit;
rit = mySet.rbegin();

mySet.erase((++rit).base());
```

the .rbegin() function returns a reverse iterator pointing to the end of the set, rit is then incremented since the base function is currently pointing to the value next to the value we want (credit to @soon for that part, in his answer). The erase() function then erases the element in the parameter.

Hope this helps. =)

Comment: @soon I seem, to have fixed it. Thanks for pointing out my error.