Address sanitizer shows a memory error in valid C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
using std::cout, std::endl;
using std::multiset;
int main() {
    multiset<int> m;
    m.insert(1);
    m.insert(2);
    m.insert(3);
    m.erase(std::prev(m.end()));
    for (auto &i : m) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

When I compile this code using g++ -o main main.cpp, it works normally. However, when I compile this code using g++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover -fstack-protector -o main main.cpp, then AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL pops up in about 1 out of 10 runs.
I am using
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
The code is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468959/19357263
Is this an error of the compiler?

please do not remove the includes etc from the code. Anybody who wants to compile your code has to add them back.

Personally, I've disabled the sanitizer shortly after adding it to my project, on account of it throwing false positives all over the place. It did give me an actual misaligned access, though -- irrelevant since the CPUs can handle it, but I fixed it anyway. Arguably, that's a more complicated thing than your "hello world"-type example, but my opinion on the sanitizer is very low...

Your code looks fine. I tried with clang 15 and there's no error. So I think it's likely a bug in the version you use. If it doesn't report the location, you can try add -g and dig more.

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL can be raised when address space layout randomization (ASLR) is enabled (default). When you run the address sanitizer, disabling ASLR should fix the issue:
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

When you're done, don't forget to re-enable ASLR and restore the protection:
echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

